# How do I erase a portion of a bitmap in Qt?

Tags: qt, bitmap, erase

Any idea on how to erase a portion of a bitmap just like Android's PorterDuff Mode?
I am creating an application like Paint, and I don't know how to erase the drawings I have written using the pen.

Any idea regarding this one?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the `QPainter` class which can perform various drawing operations on a `QBitmap` (more precisely: it draws on a `QPaintDevice`, from which `QBitmap` derives).

Among the various operations of the painter, there is `QPainter::eraseRect()` which can erase a portion of a `QBitmap`.

This is the way you use it:

```
QBitmap b;
QPainter p( &b );
p.eraseRect( x, y, w, h ); // With x, y, w and h defining the portion
                           // of your bitmap you want to erase
```